# Add text for specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I'm trying to add some text only on the specific products of determinate category in `woocommerce`, I tried to add this code in `plugins/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php` but don't work:

```
if (is_category('box-mod') || has_category('box-mod',$post->ID)) {
    echo "Message: available on march";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce categories are seperate from Posts categories so you can't use `has_category()`, you must [has_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) instead.

```
global $product;
if( has_term( 'box-mod', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
    echo "Message: available on march";
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [woocommerce_product_meta_end](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_product_meta_end/) hook if you don't want to modify the Woocommerce template files